# Turn off wine debugging

Tags: 11.10, wine

How do I make wine not showing any debug messages the default setting? I've found `WINEDEBUG=-all wine ./program.exe` as a way to turn off debug for the program I'm currently running, but how do I make it the default for everything?

Answer (score 8):

`WINEDEBUG` is an environment variable that is set for only for the invocation of `wine`.

What you need to do is make the environment variable permanent, which you can do in your `~/.bashrc`.

Open it in your favourite editor and add to the bottom:

```
export WINEDEBUG=-all
```

The next new Terminal you open will trigger that setting and `wine ./program.exe` should inherit it.

Since `.bashrc` is just a series of shell commands that are run when a Terminal is started, you can just type the same thing into a Terminal as well; but then it will be lost when you close that Terminal.